# If no records are found in the Start method of a batch class, will the Finish method still execute?

Tags: apex

I'm working on some chained jobs that need to run in a specific order. The Finish method executes the next batch in the chain. If no records are found by the start method, will the finish method still fire, or is it only after Execute runs?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, finish is guaranteed to execute, even if there are no successful calls to execute, or no calls at all. It will not be called if, and only if, the batch is aborted, or the start method encounters an uncaught exception..